# Cannot deploy metadata to Analysis Services

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, ssas-tabular

Building a tabular model in Visual Studio I'm facing an issue when trying to deploy the model to the Analysis Service Server (SQL Server 2019 Standard). I get this error:

> Cannot deploy metadata. Reason: An error occurred while connecting to the server.

I already set the deployment server in the model properties. And the last thing I tried was to set the Administrator local user of the SQL Server in the Impersonation Information dialog, but is giving me the invalid user / password error.

Also tried to use Service Account, but having the same error.

I can get the data from the SQL Server (using SQL Server Authentication) but the problem is when trying to deploy the model to the Analysis Server.

Is this error caused because the servers are not part of an AD?

Any way to work around this, or way to see any logs?

Using Visual Studio 2017 and 2019.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this error caused because the servers are not part of an AD?

Possibly.  SSAS only supports Windows Integrated Auth, so you need to make that work.  The preferred method is to deploy from a session owned by a SSAS administrator, from a workstation in the same domain.

If that's not possible there are a couple of other options.  One is to create a local account on both the workstation and the server with the same name and password, and log in as that account to deploy.

The other is to install a Windows Credential in the windows credential store for an identity that has rights to deploy to the SSAS database.  Or to run visual studio via `runas /netonly` specifying the credentials for the remote server.

Comment: When you mean "create a local account on both workstations",  should I specify the windows login in the Impersonation Information dialog? and put the <workstation name>\user or it will work with just the username?

Comment: Yes `<servername>\someuser` and `<workstationname>\someuser`.  As a shortcut you can use `.\someuser` on both the server and the workstation, and the passwords must match.

Comment: Thanks @david.!!